# Copy data File AWS S3 to Aurora Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, psql, amazon-aurora

Trying to Copy csv File from AWS S3 to Aurora Postgres.

I did add S3 access to the RDS table for s3 import.
Is there anything else i am missing?

This is command that i tried:

`SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 ('t1','','DELIMITER '','' CSV HEADER',aws_commons.create_s3_uri('testing','test_1.csv','us-west-2'));`

Error:

````
NOTICE:  HINT: make sure your instance is able to connect with S3.
NOTICE:  CURL error code: 28 when attempting to validate pre-signed URL, 0 attempt(s) remaining
NOTICE:  HINT: make sure your instance is able to connect with S3.
ERROR:  Unable to generate pre-signed url, look at engine log for details.
CONTEXT:  SQL function "table_import_from_s3" statement 1 ```



can anyone help me on this please?
````